# Angular returning null for params value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In my Angular app I am having trouble with getting the value from my params and thus data from my API call.

I keep getting `null` and `[object Object]` in browser console for my console.log

**EDIT: I have noticed that upon loading this page the tag value is overwhritten wit undefined.. image bellow:**
[image]

Here is the code I am using to get params value and show products with this tag:

**EDIT: search.service.ts file where the API is called**

```
  searchByTagCall(tag: string) {
    return from(Preferences.get({key: 'TOKEN_KEY'})).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('tag', tag);
        return this.httpClient.get(`${environment.apiUrl}search`, {headers, observe: 'response', params});
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err.status);
        if (err.status === 400) {
          console.log(err.error.message);
        }
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.authService.logout();
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', {replaceUrl: true});
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    );
  }
```

**EDIT: home.page.ts Code where I click the tag that redirects to the page where products with this tag should be shown:**

```
  searchByTag(tag: string) {
    this.tagsSubscription = this.searchService.searchByTagCall(tag).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.searchService.tag = data;
        this.router.navigate(['/tag-search/', tag]);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }
```

**and html:**

```
 <ion-chip *ngFor="let tag of tags">
    <ion-label class="tag" (click)="searchByTag(tag.tags)">{{ tag.tags }}</ion-label>
  </ion-chip>
```

**tag-search.page.ts:**

```
export class TagSearchPage implements OnInit {
  tag: string;
  products: any = [];
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private searchService: SearchService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showTagProducts();
  }

  showTagProducts() {
    const tag = String(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('tag'));

    this.searchService.searchByTagCall(tag).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log('Products with tag: ' + tag + '   ' + data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }

}
```

**Here is how my JSON response looks like:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1283,
    "name": "Some product name",
    "product_code": "470631"
  },
  {
    "id": 786,
    "name": "A different product name",
    "product_code": "460263"
  }
]
```